# Error: "Windows can't find 'C:/PROGRA~1/'. Check the spelling and try again."

Tags: r, windows, directory, process, backslash

I am getting an error in `R` in Windows 10 about finding a directory while trying to install a package from GitHub*. Trying to troubleshoot this error led me to a few observations.

For example, both Windows Explorer and my browser can find `C:/PROGRA~1`, but only my browser can find `C:/PROGRA~1/R`, where `R` is installed. The specific Windows Explorer error is:

```
Windows can't find 'C:/PROGRA~1/R'. Check the spelling and try again.
```

Yet, Windows Explorer can find `C:/Program Files/R` no problem. And the error above is the same with `C:/PROGRA~1/Adobe`, `C:/PROGRA~1/Google`, or any other. Even more interesting, Windows Explorer can't even find the raw program files path as long as we add a simple slash at the end! So `C:/PROGRA~1/` will output a similar error.

So can anyone explain to me why Windows Explorer is not able to find `C:/PROGRA~1/R` or `C:/PROGRA~1/`? Is this normal/expected? If I solve this, I can probably resolve my `R` error too. Thanks.

*Here is the full original error in `R`:

```
Error: Failed to install 'package' from GitHub:
  create process 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.3/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe' (system error 267, The directory name is invalid.
) @win/processx.c:1040 (processx_exec)
```

Edit: My investigation revealed that it might be related to the direction of slashes... So for instance, `C:/PROGRA~1\R` (or even `C:/PROGRA~1\`) works in Windows Explorer, but only as long as the second slash is a backslash... Can this be of any help in resolving this issue? Doesn't seem like `R` wants to put that second slash as backslash...

Edit 2: My answer below was deleted so here it is again:

> The issue was with the processx package and the development version has since received a fix (in version v3.5.3). Please see the following discussion for more info: https://github.com/r-lib/processx/issues/313

Comment: I just now found your question. I had the exactly same error, and created a [bug report](https://github.com/r-lib/processx/issues/313) on GitHub of processx. Meanwhile there is a workaround for people trying to solve this. Check out this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68400661/r-unable-to-install-packages-from-github-system-error-267-win-processx-c1040/68408378#68408378)

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that I had both, %OneDrive% and %OneDriveCommercial% env variables pointing to the same company onedrive folder, which I suspect to have caused a confusion!
I deleted the %OneDrive%, and revised all the other envs to make sure that it is not referenced anywhere else.